# url customize in yii

Tags: php, yii

> This is my url i want to remove
>   **providerguid/8469d0c7ddea6e568381c5ed24ecca88**

this is my link :-  http://localhost/frontsite/agemodern/site/steps/providerdetails/providerguid/8469d0c7ddea6e568381c5ed24ecca88.

for remove the providerguid i use :-

```
   '/steps/providerdetails/<providerguid:\w+>'=>'/site/steps/providerdetails/providerguid/<providerguid>',
```

but its only remove the providerguid key not all like providerguid/8469d0c7ddea6e568381c5ed24ecca88

I have also try for this :

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s([^.]+)\.php\?urlname=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?id=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
'site/steps/providerdetails/providerguid/<providerguid:\w+>'=>'/site/steps/providerdetails/providerguid/<providerguid>'
```

Comment: i have try this ,but this is only remove the name of providerguid don't remove providerguid/8469d0c7ddea6e568381c5ed24ecca88

Comment: @gouravsharma: sorry, I forget to add the `site`. Look at the edited answer